# How to convert package into pure js files?

Tags: meteor

I am currently on a project made with meteor, and former developer created some packages, and the project looks like this:

```
/projectName
|- /client
|- /server
|- /lib
|- /packages
|- /packages/projectName-packageName1
|- /packages/projectName-packageName2
```

And the team leader asked me to rebuild the project with meteor 1.x and move all packages under `/pacakages` into `/lib`.

I'm new to meteor and tried to move the files under `/packages` into `/lib` directly and of course with no success.

Could you please intelligent me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can just copy paste the code but you should aware on some things.

If your packages are only server side or don't play with `DOM Elements` or the Window Object it should work, just be sure that you have all the dependencies this packages need to work.(the `/lib folder` is shared between *server/client* and the Window Object dosnt exists on the server).

First open the `package.js` of each package and see wich files belongs to the server and wich files belongs to the client, so just grab that files and put under the respective folder `/client` `/server` or `/both`.

Second take a look into api.use, for example.

```
api.use('coffeescript','client')
```

if you have something like this now you should do a `meteor add coffeescript` manual.

Also since meteor loads first the package before any other `file/folder` inside the app, you should be aware about how the apps load now.

But in resume yes, you can just copy paste the `code/files` and put them in the correct folder and it should work.